Movie about two (three?) sisters, ending with "can't board airplane without shoes"
Honest 15-20 years ago, I've watched this one good old movie...  with two sisters (or maybe good friends)... one of them was the singer of some musical band, or something like that... short-haired male-like cut, eccentric, troublemaker. The movie is ending with an airport situation, when the girl was desperate (after some of her recent problems) and wanted to fly somewhere on an airplane. The personnel did not want to let her in, as she was not wearing any shoes. Finally, after some citation like "it's a medical emergency", one of the waiting passengers gave her his shoes, so that she could get in.
I'm still not sure if it was some B-class movie or some kind of arthouse movie, as the story was very naturalistically presented.
Could somebody help me to identify which movie was it?

Sounds like Georgia from 1995 about a drug-addicted singer (played by a short-haired Jennifer Jason Leigh) and her sister. You can see the airport scene you've described (she claims it's a medical emergency; she's not allowed to board the plane without shoes; a young passanger gives her his) here from 1:50 until 4:32.
